# How to make ZeroMQ PUSH / PULL work with identity?

Tags: zeromq

I have an application that has an all-to-all communication pattern. I think it makes sense to have one `PULL` socket and one `PUSH` socket on each of the N processes, and have all the `PUSH` sockets connect to all the `PULL` sockets. But rather than selecting the receiver in a round-robin way, I want to send to a specific receiver selectively, in a case by case manner. For example, if I want to send a message from the `PUSH` socket of process-**`i`** to the `PULL` socket of process-**`j`**, do you know how to do that?

FOLLOW UP 1:

One solution that I can think of is to create one `ROUTER` socket on each process, and each `ROUTER` socket will connect to all the `ROUTER` sockets of the other processes (all-to-all connection). Will that work?

FOLLOW UP 2:

Another solution that I can think of is to use `ROUTER` and `DEALER` socket instead. Maybe I can have each process create one `DEALER` socket to connect to the `ROUTER` socket of each of the other processes (multiple all-to-one connections). Is it a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

If indeed a friend of a fully ( internally ) meshed star topology, maybe the `PUB/SUB` with TOPIC-filter may work for your scenario sufficiently well.

All `SUB`-s will `.connect()` to `PUB`-s, that `.bind()`, reverse `.bind()/.connect()`-s are also feasible. The newer version does PUB-side TOPIC-filtering, so within some reasonably sized **`N`**-s the scheme shall suffice. `.setsockopt()` tweaking is obvious and needed.

As neither latency, cadency or message-sizes were mentioned, it is hard to compare a fully-meshed star topology's cons+pros against a "soft"-controlled rotary-passing or other low-resources consuming approach.

> <sub>( I am still using **ZeroMQ 2.1.11** and love to do it )</sub>

May also like [this new, custom-made scalable formal communication pattern design example](http://vitiy.info/writing-custom-protocol-for-nanomsg/) - out of question an interesting approach for Martin SUSTRIK's [nanomsg](/questions/tagged/nanomsg) lovely engine, if in a need to scale beyond ~10k+ agents.